# Unresponsive desktop after login because of maya

Tags: greeter, desktop, gala, calendar, processes

Just had a problem after rebooting my computer this morning; after the successful login I saw the wallpaper appearing, then wingpanel appeared and 5 seconds later it froze; plank did not appear and all I could do was to move the mouse cursor. After waiting a few minutes, nothing changed.

I switched to a VT (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and launched `htop` - no process was unusually high on the CPU; looked in the logs - no error message. I killed the gala process tree and was promptly brought to the login screen.

After logging in this time, the desktop appeared normally (wingpanel and plank started almost instantaneously) and I was immediately prompted with the login screen from maya, complaining about the certificate.

Can this be a flaw in the desktop launching logic? If yes, how can it be corrected?

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same unresponsive behaviour yesterday after an update. I couldn't track it down to Maya, but basicly the whole system froze a few seconds after login.

For me, the issue was resolved today by updating the system again:

1. Go to console after the system has started up (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or just <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>)
2. Run `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get upgrade`
3. Reboot

Comment: It was not the same for me (in the end I had found a workaround as described); no previous updates that I could blame; also the freeze was persistent - even between succesive reboots. The "solution" came once I killed gala and I logged in again; this time the desktop  libraries were already loaded in memory and the startup time was short, so the Maya login screen could not be triggered before wingpanel and plank had finished their initialization. My question was about some flawed logic behind the initialization of the modules - a simple dialog can trigger some sort of DoS.